# How to Hide the up or down arrow key when scrolling at the end of the Jscrollpane

Tags: jscrollpane, arrow-keys

I used the JScrollPane from http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ and modified it to hide the arrow key when scrolling at the end (top or bottom). When scrollbar is at the top, the arrowUp should disappear, showing only arrowDown at the bottom and appears again when scrolling down.

I've made the arrow image disappear at the top, but the problem is the scroll track does not change but just adds extra space equal to the size of the arrow image at the very bottom. How can I go around this, how do I change it so that when the arrow is hidden at one end, the jspTrack's height is adjusted as well, showing the other arrow on the opposite end without extra space?

```
if (settings.showArrows) {

                if(isAtTop){
                    arrowUp.addClass('jspDisabled');
                    arrowUp.css('display', 'none');
                }
                else{
                    arrowUp.removeClass('jspDisabled');
                    arrowUp.css('display', 'block');
                }

                if(isAtBottom){
                    arrowDown.addClass('jspDisabled');
                    arrowDown.css('display', 'none');
                }
                else{
                    arrowUp.removeClass('jspDisabled');
                    arrowDown.css('display', 'block');
                }

                /*arrowUp[isAtTop ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('jspDisabled');
                arrowDown[isAtBottom ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('jspDisabled');*/



            }
```

Thanks all.

Comment: I would either leave them both always or remove them both always for the sake of usability.  Is there any specific reason why you want to remove one or the other when it is at either max top or max bottom? Or is it client or personal preference?

Comment: Hi Richard, it's client preference. Is there a way to do that? or if at least someone can point me to the right direction...Thanks

Comment: you will need to reset the scroller height and possibly remove and reattach the scroller once you get to the top to compensate the height of the arrows.  there will be sort of a snapping once you get to the top or bottom because. now you see it now you don't even if your just 1px of the top it will appear then jump down again. and as soon as you hit the max top the bar will jump up 10px because its now at the "top".. you'd almost have to create an animation that made the transition smoother you can't work some smooth talk'n?  There's really no "easy" way sometimes you just gotta say "No" dude.

Comment: just kill the arrows all touch device have killed the arrows even OSX Lion doesn't use them any more.. if this is still an issue then its a design issue.

Comment: I figured as soon as I had problems doing it. Thanks for the input. probably have to let that bit out. too complex. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

you can control it via css

```
<style>
.jspVerticalBar{
  background:none;
}
.jspVerticalBar .jspArrow{
  display:block;
}
.jspVerticalBar .jspDisabled
{
  display:none;
}
</style>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
 $('.pane').jScrollPane({showArrows:true});
</script>
```